# SQL window function to fill gaps on daily values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset as follows:

```
+---------------------+---------+--------+
| timestamp           | person  | value  |
|---------------------+---------+--------|
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 1       | 0.01   |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 2       | 0      |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 3       | 1      |

| 2022-06-02 07:00:00 | 1       | 0.15   |
| 2022-06-02 07:00:00 | 2       | 0.5    |

| 2021-06-03 01:00:00 | 1       | 0.03   |
+---------------------+---------+--------+
```

And I want to fill gaps, such that each person shows up everyday if they are not already present. For example: Person 3 has a value 1 on 2022-06-01, but doesn't show up on 2022-06-02, thus this record should up on 2022-06-02 with the previous day's value. But if Person 3 already had a record on 2022-06-02 then we do nothing.

```
+---------------------+---------+--------+
| timestamp           | person  | value  |
|---------------------+---------+--------|
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 1       | 0.01   |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 2       | 0      |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 3       | 1      | 

| 2022-06-02 07:00:00 | 1       | 0.15   |
| 2022-06-02 07:00:00 | 2       | 0.5    |
| 2022-06-02 00:00:00 | 3       | 1      |

| 2021-06-03 01:00:00 | 1       | 0.03   |
| 2022-06-03 01:00:00 | 2       | 0.5    |
| 2022-06-03 01:00:00 | 3       | 1      |
+---------------------+---------+--------+
```

I think this can be done by a series generation and a window function but I can't seem to get a working solution. (An efficient solution is needed as the source table is quite large)

Thanks in advance for any response!

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select if(date = date(timestamp), timestamp(timestamp), timestamp(date)) timestamp, person, value
from (
  select *, coalesce(
    first_value(date(timestamp)) over next_date - 1,
    max(date(timestamp)) over last_date,
    date(timestamp)) next_date
  from your_table
  window last_date as (order by unix_date(date(timestamp)) range between 1 following and unbounded following),
    next_date as (partition by person order by unix_date(date(timestamp)) range between 1 following and unbounded following)
), unnest(generate_date_array(date(timestamp), next_date)) date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approache would be

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(timestamp, timestamp(date)) timestamp,
       p.person,
       LAST_VALUE(s.value IGNORE NULLS) OVER w value
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(timestamp) date FROM sample) t,
       (SELECT DISTINCT person FROM sample) p
  LEFT JOIN sample s ON t.date = DATE(s.timestamp) AND p.person = s.person
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY p.person ORDER BY COALESCE(timestamp, timestamp(date)));
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that if some day(s) are missing for all persons - that day will be also missed in the output!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, good point. thanks for pointing that out. yes, it has an assumption data is big enough not to have missing days. If there are missing days, i thinks using **generate_date_array(min(date(timestamp)), nax(date(timtstamp))** instead of **distinct date(timestamp)** may resolve this issue.